# $a \equiv b \mod k \implies a \equiv ? \mod k^2$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-set-theory, modular-arithmetic

Is there any modular law such that:

> $a \equiv b \mod k \implies a \equiv ? \mod k^2$

I know that 
$$ a \equiv b \mod k \implies a^n \equiv b^n \mod k $$
but sometimes I need to power only $k$ and then there are examples when it is not so easy to investigate without any theorem.

Comment: Well, $1\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $1\equiv 1 \pmod {25}$ but $6\equiv 1 \pmod 5$ and $6\equiv 6\pmod {25}$ so just knowing $a\pmod k$ does not determine $a\pmod {k^2}$.

Comment: I'd say putting $?=a$ should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The left hand side means $k\mid(a-b)$. Square to get $k^2\mid (a-b)^2$. You can write that as $a\equiv a^2+(1-2b)a+b^2\bmod{k^2}$, though it is a bit artificial.

Answer (score 1):

Since you only know $a\equiv b\mod k$, then $a=b+jk$ for some $j$. Now, this last expression mod $k^2$ depends only in $j\mod k$, what I am trying to say is $b+jk\equiv b+j'k\mod k^2$ if $j\equiv j'\mod k$. So, what we can say is that $a\equiv b+jk\mod k^2$ for some $j\mod k$, in better words: $$a\equiv b+jk\mod k^2\hbox{ for some } j=0,1,\dots ,k-1$$